# How does a minor major seventh chord have tonic function when it's so unstable?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, jazz, functional-harmony

In a minor key, the chord built on the tonic can be a minor sixth or a minor major seventh chord, both of which are supposed to have tonic function. To my ear, the minor sixth chord can feel like "home", but I've always heard the minor major seventh chord as being too unstable to sit on because of the augmented triad inside it. How is it supposed to have tonic function then? (I know it's the **I** chord in harmonic (or melodic) minor. My question is how it can have its supposed *harmonic function*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While generally in functional harmony chords build on the **i** are considered to have tonic function, this is not always the case, especially when using non-traditional chord like the minor 6<sup>th</sup> or the minor major 7<sup>th</sup>. The minor 6<sup>th</sup> does not come from either the *natural or harmonic minor scales*, the scales most often used to build chords in the minor key. It can be considered to come from the *melodic minor scale* as you state in your question. I have mostly heard that it's from the *dorian mode*. On the other hand, the minor major 7 can be considered to be build using the *harmonic minor* scale. This is an atypical use of the *harmonic minor* scale as mostly it is just used to build a dominant **V** chord (or sometimes a **vii<sup>o</sup>** chord). To my knowledge, both of these chords come from jazz theory and do not follow the typical rules of functional harmony.

So, to the nitty-gritty. Both minor 6<sup>th</sup>s and minor major 7<sup>th</sup>s *can* be considered to have tonic function, but do not necessarily have tonic function given certain circumstances. The tritone in the minor 6<sup>th</sup> and augmented 5<sup>th</sup> in the minor major 7<sup>th</sup> are prone to sounding resolved when moved. A minor 6<sup>th</sup> build on the tonic is enharmonically equivalent to a diminished 7<sup>th</sup> built on the 6<sup>th</sup> scale degree. Meaning it can act as a secondary dominant, specifially the **vii<sup>o</sup>/♭VII**, **ii<sup>o</sup>/v**, **iv<sup>o</sup>/III**, or **vi<sup>o</sup>/♯i** (not 100% sure about the last two). Further, I've seen the minor major 7<sup>th</sup> resolve to the **♭III** chord; the augmented 5<sup>th</sup> interval falls down to a perfect 5<sup>th</sup> interval. This can tonicize the relative major. All that is to say, these chords can be very directional and have clear dominant function even if build on the 1<sup>st</sup> scale degree.

If you want to establish tonic function with one of those chords here are a few suggestions:

- Stay on the home chord. Eventually, any chord or structure you sit on will become tonicized.
- Try a two-chord vamp. Switch between your chord of choice and the root triad.
- Move to the minor 6<sup>th</sup> or minor major 7<sup>th</sup> chord with a dominant function chord like the **V** or the **vii<sup>o</sup>**.
- Move away from minor 6<sup>th</sup> or minor major 7<sup>th</sup> chord in such a way that doesn't show a clear resolution. See above for chords *not* to go to.

Lastly, to your point of minor major 7<sup>th</sup> chords sounding less able to be tonicized than a minor 6<sup>th</sup> chord. Quite possibly this is due to the fact that we are much less familiar with augmented triads than diminished ones in western music. Particularly, this is true if you listen to a lot of blues where dominant 7<sup>th</sup> chords are ubiquitous (the upper structure being a diminished triad).

Comment: I've only ever come across mM7 as a 'stepping stone' chord - usually between tonic  m to m7. This Masquerade is an example. It's hardly a chord to finish a piece on, so 'tonic function' seems a strange term to blight it with.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Fair point about unstable intervals in both "tonic" dominant seventh chords and minor sixth chords which I don't have a problem with. It probably is just being used to that sound from the blues.

Comment: it's not to do with familiarity, the minor 6th is an inherently stable chord, acoustically speaking.  The minor major seventh most certainly isn't.